# Is there a shorthand way of mocking several methods at once in PHPUnit?

Tags: mocking, phpunit

Suppose I have this:

```
$mock = $this->createMock(\MyClass::class);
$mock->method('foo')
  ->willReturn('data');
$mock->method('bar')
  ->willReturn('data');
```

Is there a shorthand to say that both methods (or more) will return the same thing?

Comment: Does the given answer suit your question ? Maybe including the code in an helper method ?

Comment: Yup, it certainly is DRY, which was what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Configured mock

You can use the [createConfiguredMock($originalClassName, array $configuration)](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6.0/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1461) method of the *TestCase* class:

```
$this->createConfiguredMock(\MyClass::class, [
    'foo' => 'data',
    'bar' => 'data'
]);
```

You still need to specify the returned value for each method, but it is the best shorthand given by PHPUnit I know about.

But you can **generate the configuration** array as follow:

```
$this->createConfiguredMock(\MyClass::class, array_fill_keys([
    'foo',
    'bar'
], 'data'));
```